# Identify BlackBerry devices with at runtime with Java

Tags: java, blackberry, device, blackberry-storm

How to identify the Blackberry device currently running the application?
For example: how to identify whether the current device is a Storm or a Torch?

BlackBerry Storm 2 (9520/9550)
BlackBerry Tour (9630)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `DeviceInfo.getDeviceId();` as shown [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Method-to-get-device-ID/m-p/205656)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [this article](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/1620-retrieve-model-info-java.html) and read the [DeviceInfo.getDeviceName() and DeviceInfo.getDeviceId() documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html)?

Comment: it's better to present your answer as an answer, instead of a question.